# How many levels of strictness of positive obligations are there?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, halacha-theory

When learning Halachic books from the Talmud through Rambam and Shu"A to Mishnah Berurah, one meets different levels of positive commandments that reflect different levels of obligation/strictness/importance/effort, such as

- Mitzvah DeOraytah / Mitzvah DeRabannan / Positive deed / Accepted tradition etc.

Many different words are used, for example "וכך נהגים", "עושה אדם ...", "ויש לו ...", "מצווה עליו...", "חייב אדם...", "הורו רבותינו...", "התפשט המנהג / הדבר...", and more.

Theoretically, we could give each Mitzvah a score of "severity", for example, the obligation of reading Shemah precedes the obligations of its Berachot or Psukey Dezimrah in strictness. The Mishnah Avot (2,1) says "והוי זהיר במצוה קלה כבחמורה, שאין אתה יודע מתן שכרן של מצוות", so there are at least two sorts of Mitzvot - קלות and חמורות.

Roughly how many levels of strictness of "all good deeds" are there?

Comment: I do not agree with the downvote. Could you please give all the Hebrew terms for "Positive deed / Accepted tradition etc." as used in the sources you quote? What do you mean by "the languages (in Shu"A or MB) are very confusing" - can you give examples please?

Comment: AFAIK d'rabbanans are not less important/exigent than d'oraisas. (According to some textual evidence, the contrary is true.) The only difference with drabbanans is that they can be more easily limited *by those who are making the law.*

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok For example "וכך נהגים", "עושה אדם ...", "ויש לו ...", "מצווה עליו...", "חייב אדם...",  "הורו רבותינו...", "התפשט המנהג / הדבר...", and more.

Comment: @SAH Of course they are, but **to enforce them** Rabanan stressed their importance *as if* they were as important as D'Oraytah. Give me examples where a Derabanan regulation overrides a Mitzvah Doraytah?

Comment: @AlBerko I'm pretty sure there are a couple cases where a rabbinical aseh override s a Torah lo taaseh

Comment: @AlBerko Anyway, the point I was trying to make is that "ability to override" is not fungible with importance.

Comment: I am sorely tempted to close this as too broad. There’s tons of different levels, especially in light of your recent comment. A lot of them might be the author’s style; one author’s “חייב אדם” might be another’s “מצוה על כל אדם,” and it’s no indication that they are different “levels.” I’m not even entirely sure that it necessarily makes a difference even when they’re said by the *same* author.

Comment: @DonielF Why would that be too broad, and not simply the answer to the question?